# How can I make the WebBrowser control navigate to a specific address?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I make the code when run the code it go to example.com

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("www.example.com");
}
```

Please correct it when run program it go to example.com

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("www.example.com");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        if (document != null)
        {
            IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;    
            IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            if (range != null)
            {
                const String search = "ant";
                if (range.findText(search, search.Length, 2))
                {
                    range.select();
                }
            }
        }
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you Navigate to example.com at `Form.Load` event?  It's working fine in my machine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("www.example.com"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question: The `e` variable in the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method contains the `Url` property that holds the current [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object with the URL where the browser control has arrived:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    if (e.Url.Host.EndsWith("example.com"))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the [`Load` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) of your form (`Form1`) if you want the `WebBrowser` control to automatically navigate to www.example.com whenever your form is shown on the screen.

As it's written now, you handle the [`Navigated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) of the `WebBrowser` control and tell it to navigate somewhere else. However, the `Navigated` event is only raised when the browser has navigated to and begun loading a new page. Even if you get your code to work, it will be perpetually chasing its own tail.

Instead, try the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com"); 
}
```

This execute the navigate method after the app is initialized.